# React hoc for disabling fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react I have a bunch of forms in my app and based on the users type(admin, etc...), determines whether the inputs are disabled or not. I made a separate file for the components and there must be a better way of doing it:

```
export const Select = props => {
  const { isAdmin } = useAppContext();
  return <AntdSelect disabled={!isAdmin} {...props} />;
};
export const Input = props => {
  const { isAdmin } = useAppContext();
  return <AntdInput disabled={!isAdmin} {...props} />;
};
export const Switch = props => {
  const { isAdmin } = useAppContext();
  return <AntdSwitch disabled={!isAdmin} {...props} />;
};
```

basically I extract isAdmin from my context var but I dont want to do this for every component. What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question but you can do something like this.

```
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable
  const { isAdmin } = useAppContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <AntdSelect disabled={!isAdmin}  />;
      <AntdInput disabled={!isAdmin}  />;
      <AntdSwitch disabled={!isAdmin}  />;
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are losing values from props (probably label, type and others) and render blank Select, Input and Switch. If is isAdmin is true those fields will be active.

Comment: you can also send props if u have any like the way u did or u can send new props for component for example :

 `<AntdSelect disabled={!isAdmin}  sampleProp={sampledata}  {...props} />`

Comment: and from what I saw you read admin privilege from context and u get the same answer every time its true so if isAdmin is true in the first component it will stay true through the second and third component

Comment: The point of my question was so that i dont need to declare `isAdmin` in every component. I would just need to import `<Input />` whenever I need it

Comment: well all I'm saying is that your isAdmin variable should come from somewhere and u can pass it to the component as a props be sure to fully understand the props in react